# mvc layout page misbehaving with ui in mobile devices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, layout

I am creating a web app in `mvc` using `Javascript` and `Jquery`.

when I comment the line for layout which is below,

```
//Layout = "~/Views/Shared/myLayout.cshtml";
```

[image: this]

my ui looks fine in all the mobile devices, but when I un-comment this line like the following,

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/myLayout.cshtml";
```

[image: this]

my font-size decreases and it makes very difficult to understand,

> `my myLayout.cshtml is empty`

what is the problem here and how can I solve this?

Comment: could you please share your code for myLayout.cshtml and the view?

Comment: myLayout.cshtml is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly edit your myLayout.cshtml to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your view, remove all the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

The trick here is `<meta>` tag. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).